# How do you hide an expanded tableviews label when it is expanded? - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, expand

I would like to hide an expanded tableviews label, when the cell is expanded and hide a button when it is collapsed. I have my cell implementation in another class, with the property of the label and the button in the header. The problem is that when I call these cell methods in the ExpandedViewController, the code goes into the method, but it won't change the properties behaviour. Could you possibly help me with this issue?

Thank you

ExpandedCell.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *setTime;
```

ExpandedCell.m

```
(void)setIfHidden:(BOOL)showIfHidden
{ 
if (showIfHidden)
{
[self.lblTitle setHidden:YES];
[self.setTime setHidden:NO];
}
else
{
[self.lblTitle setHidden:NO];
[self.setTime setHidden:YES];
}  
}
```

ExpandedViewController.m

```
import ExpandedCell.h
```

.

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath])
{   
    return CELL_HEIGHT_EXPANDED;
}
else
{
    return CELL_HEIGHT_COLLAPSED;
}
}
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
self.expandedIndexPath = ([self.expandedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) ? nil : indexPath;

ExpandedCell *hideCell = [[ExpandedCell alloc] init];
showIfHidden = YES;

[hideCell setIfHidden:showIfHidden];

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/bennyguitar/CollapseClick 
https://github.com/iSofTom/STCollapseTableView
check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties are labelled as `IBOutlet`s. You create a new instance of the cell with `[[ExpandedCell alloc] init]`.

You have a few issues:

1. By calling `alloc init` the `IBOutlet`s won't exist because the instance isn't unarchived from a NIB file.
2. Once you create `hideCell`, you call a method on it and then it gets destroyed (because nothing retains it).
3. You shouldn't be creating a new cell, you should be accessing and updating the existing one, so you should be using:

---

```
ExpandedCell *hideCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```